# Vlookup in Macro Loop Within a Table

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am trying to calculate a `VLookup` "off sheet" (I do not want to place a formula into the cells then copy and paste as values - rather I want to do the calculation then have the result placed into the cells as a value)

I have a table which I add data to each month. I only want to calculate the `VLookup` for the new rows (blanks).  The `VLookup` result should go in Column A of the table titled "Regionals". The table array is a table called "Orgs" which is on a different worksheet called "PAS".  The below formula retrieve the result I am looking for if I put it directly onto the worksheet (in this example the "blank" was in cell A174560).

- The main table where the `VLookup` occurs is titled "Table6"
- Main table is on a worksheet titled "TAB"
- Column B (value to lookup) is titled "County Codes" on the table

`=VLOOKUP(B174560,Orgs[[#All],[County]:[Regional]],4,FALSE)`

The code I have now:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each cell In Range("Table6[Regionals]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    cell.Value = [Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cells(CELL.row,Worksheets("TAB").Range("Table6[County Codes]").column)),Worksheets("PAS").Range("Orgs[#All]),[County]:[Regional]"),4,false)]
Next
```

The code runs without error, but places a `#VALUE` error in the blank cell.

I am guessing the issue lies in the syntax of using table names and columns names within the tables or from my attempt to use the cells format within the vlookup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim addr, col As Long


With Worksheets("TAB")

   col = .Range("Table6[County Codes]").column

   For Each cell In  .Range("Table6[Regionals]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells

        addr = .Cells(cell.Row, col).Address()

        cell.value = .Evaluate("VLOOKUP(" & addr & _
                         ",Orgs[[#All],[County]:[Regional]],4,FALSE)")
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Could you explain the syntax of the code below:

    " & addr & "

I'm unsure of why you could not simply use :

    VLOOKUP(addr,

Thanks!